# TypeError: tempItems.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku

So I keep getting this error:

```
TypeError: tempItems.map is not a function
ApiCalls.render
src/ApiCalls.js:58
  55 | console.log("THIS IS TEMP ITEMS: " + tempItems);
  56 | return (
  57 |   <div className="articles">
-> 58 |     {tempItems.map(item => (
  59 |       <ArticleCard key={item.title} title={item.title} desc={item.description} imgsrc={item.urlToImage} url={item.url}/>
  60 |     ))}
  61 |   </div>
View compiled
▶ 18 stack frames were collapsed.
(anonymous function)
src/ApiCalls.js:20
  17 | .then(res => res.json())
  18 | .then(
  19 |   (result) => {
-> 20 |     this.setState({
  21 |       isLoaded: true,
  22 |       items: result.articles
  23 |     });
```

Initially, I didn't have the tempItems object, and just had items and was getting the same error. I read somewhere online that the error was occurring because items could be null, so I put in a tempItems with the data the program should use if items is not populated, but its giving me the same error. Idk what to do :( Please help

Code inside of ApiCalls.js (handles my api calls)

```
render() {
    const { error, isLoaded, items } = this.state;
    if (error) {
      return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
    } else if (!isLoaded) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    } else {
      let tempItems = {/////////////////////////a placeholder for the raw data from the api i'm using};
      if(items){
        console.log(items);
        return (
          <div className="articles">
            {items.map(item => (
              <ArticleCard key={item.title} title={item.title} desc={item.description} imgsrc={item.urlToImage} url={item.url}/>
            ))}
          </div>
        );
      } else {
        console.log("THIS IS TEMP ITEMS: " + tempItems);
        return (
          <div className="articles">
            {tempItems.map(item => (
              <ArticleCard key={item.title} title={item.title} desc={item.description} imgsrc={item.urlToImage} url={item.url}/>
            ))}
          </div>
        );
      }
```

Comment: It appears as if `tempItems` is not an array.  Where you are doing `console.log("THIS IS TEMP ITEMS: " + tempItems);`, call `console.log(Array.isArray(tempItems)` to make sure `tempItems` is an array.

Comment: Will `tempItems` be an array of objects? If so I can update my answer to further help the solution

Answer (score 0):

tempItems is an object literal, the `.map()` function only works on arrays. You can convert it to an array using the following which will make a 2 dimensional array where index `0` of `n` is the field name and `1` is its value.

```js
var tempItems = {
  thisis: "a test",
  value: true
}

var tempItemsArr = Object.keys(tempItems).map(function(key) {
  return [key, tempItems[key]];
});

console.log(tempItemsArr);
```

After this you can successfully use the `.map()` function but you may have to tweak it a little to be compatible with a 2 dimensional array